# Display lines in a Makefile matching a certain criteria

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I've got a lot of make files in a project and I want a grep/sed regular expression to print all lines in make file in project which have non-implicit targets. For example, in the sample below, I've got `all`, `test` and `clean` as non-implicit targets but not `.c.o.`

```
#
# This is and example make file:
#

CFLAGS = --std=c99 -0
OBJS = foo.o bar.o baz.o
CC=arm-eabi-gcc

all: test

test: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
    strip $@

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

If these are printed on console it would be good enough. With this I know which make files need modification. There are other scenarios as well, but if I get this working I can tweak that regular expression for other cases as well.

So ideally I am looking for command which if run on above make file only prints...

```
all: test
test: $(OBJS)
clean:
```

Comment: Post your attempts. So that we could understand your needs.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty confusing your requirements. Please be more specific according to cases.

Comment: I just need to print those lines in make file with implicit target, i am working on my regular expression and currently i am able to print all lines with no comments i.e. i am using grep ^[^#\;] MakeFile...

Comment: When posting questions its best not to assume the people reading them are familiar with the domain you work in. For example, many people reading this will have no idea what you mean by "implicit/non-implicit target" but might very well be able to help you parse your text file and produce the output you want if you simply tell them how to identify the lines you are interested in in the input file instead of assuming "non-implicit target" conveys that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
grep '^[^!.#\;]*:' MakeFile
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't match your spec exactly, but I think it could be useful posting it too (and can be adapted with minor changes):

```
sed -n 's/^\([^.%#[:space:]]*\):.*$/\1/p' makefile
```

- **`-n`** Disables default sed behaviour of printing all lines to stdout
- **`^[^.%#[:space:]]`** Matches lines that *don't* start with `.`, `%`, `#` or any whitespace character.
- All characters until the first `:` are captured.
- The rest of the line is matched with `.*$`
- Then, the whole line is substituted by the captured part
- The `p` command prints the transformed line, and thus, the captured part.

Example output, on your makefile:

```
all
test
clean
```

Comment: `sed -n '/^[^.%#[:space:]]*:.*$/p' makefile` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there must contain only alphabets before `:`, if yes then you could try the below.

```
$ grep '^[a-zA-Z]\+:' file
all: test
test: $(OBJS)
clean:
```